# Escaping HTML characters with UTF-8?

Tags: html, encoding

If my site is using UTF-8, is there any advantage/disadvantage to still escaping HTML characters? e.g. Using `"&amp;`" instead of just "`&`"? What's the best practice?

Comment: `&` is a low-order ASCII character.  It has nothing to do with Unicode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to escape characters that have a special meaning in HTML, like `<`, `>`, `&`, to avoid parser ambiguities/invalid syntax. That has nothing to do with the encoding. You *don't* need to escape every non-ASCII character though, like "ö" to `&ouml;`, since you can natively represent them in the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: For the first question, see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371493/what-are-the-reserved-characters-in-xhtml). For the general concept, see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 0):

`&` is invalid HTML (it's an unterminated entity reference).
This has nothing to do with Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert to entity < > & always, and " only when in a html attribute

for example

```
<a title="tell me &quot;more&quot;">
```