# What Are The Reserved Characters In (X)HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, html-entities, html-encode

Yes, I've googled it, and surprisingly got confusing answers.

[One page says](http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/computing/research/cseg/projects/ariadne/ihe/web/chars.html) that `< > & "` are the only reserved characters in (X)HTML. No doubt, this makes sense.

[This page says](http://www.hiddenboston.com/webmasters/reservedcharacters.html) `< > & " '` are the reserved characters in (X)HTML. A little confusing, but okay, this makes sense too.

And then comes [this page](http://www.yourwebskills.com/specialchars.php) which says `< > & " © ° £` and non-breaking space (`&nbsp`) are all reserved characters in (X)HTML. This makes no sense at all, and pretty much adds to my confusion.

Can someone knowledgeable, who actually do know this stuff, clarify which the *reserved characters in (X)HTML* actually are?

**EDIT**: Also, should all the reserved characters in code be escaped when wrapped in `<pre>` tag? or is it just these three -- `< > &` ??

Comment: `<pre>` has no special meaning as far as parsing is concerned.

Comment: @Quentin Hmm... you are indeed right.

Comment: Answers below. To clarify, those links you mention all have it wrong! for instance, in XML, `< > & " '` are _special_ characters, in that they have entity names; but they are not _reserved_ like the pages think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only `<` and `&` **need** to be escaped. Inside attributes, `"` or `'` (depending on which quote style you use for the attribute's value) needs to be escaped, too.

```
<a href="#" onclick="here you can use ' safely"></a>
<a href="#" onclick='here you can use " safely'></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the question is not just about what needs to be escaped, although that's just what I want :) Also, can you please provide me an example for this: `Inside attributes, " or ' (depending on which quote style you use for the attribute's value) needs to be escaped, too.`

Comment: Okay, just got your edit. So, what actually are the reserved characters? Is there no specific number of them?

Comment: It depends on the context. Only `<` and `&` are always "reserved".

Answer (score 10):

The XHTML 1.0 specification states at http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/#xhtml:

> XHTML 1.0 [...] is a reformulation of the three HTML 4 document types as
>   applications of XML 1.0 [XML].

The XML 1.0 specification states at http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax:

> Character Data and Markup: Text consists of intermingled character
>   data and markup. [...] The ampersand character (`&`) and the left angle
>   bracket (`<`) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as
>   markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a
>   CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped
>   using either numeric character references or the strings "`&amp;`" and
>   "`&lt;`" respectively. The right angle bracket (`>`) may be represented
>   using the string "`&gt;`", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped
>   using either "`&gt;`" or a character reference when it appears in the
>   string "`]]>`" in content, when that string is not marking the end of
>   a CDATA section.

This means that when writing the text parts of an XHTML document you **must** escape &, <, and >.

You **can** escape a lot more, e.g. &uuml; for umlaut u. You can as well state that the document is encoded in for example UTF-8 and write the byte sequence 0xc3bc instead to get the same umlaut u.

When writing the element parts (col. "tags") of the document, there are different rules. You have to take care of ", ' and a lot of rules concerning comments, CDATA and so on. There are also rules which characters can be used in element and attribute names. You can look it up in the XML specification, but in the end it comes down to: for element and attribute names, use letters, digits and "-"; do not use "_". For attribute values, you **must** escape & and (depending on the quote style) either ' or ".

If you use one of the many libraries to write XML / XHTML documents, somebody else has already taken care of this and you just have to tell the library to write text or elements. All the escaping is done the in the background.&

Answer (score 1):

By writing "(X)HTML", you are asking (at least) two different questions.

By the HTML rules, with "HTML" meaning any HTML version up to and including HTML 4.01, only "<" and "&" are reserved. The rules are somewhat complex. They should not not appear literally except in their syntactic use in tags, entity references, and character references. But by the formal rules, they may appear literally e.g. in the context "A & B" or "A < B" (but `A&B` be formally wrong, and so would `A<B`).

The XHTML rules, based on XML, are somewhat stricter, simpler: "<" and "&" are unconditionally reserved.

The ASCII quotation mark " and the ASCII apostrophe ' are not reserved, except in the very specific sense that a quoted attribute value must not literally contain the character used as quote, i.e. in "foo" the string foo must not contain " as such and in 'foo' the string foo must not contain ' as such.

Comment: I didn't understand this bit: `But by the formal rules, they may appear literally e.g. in the context "A & B" or "A < B" (but A&B be formally wrong, and so would A<B).` What's the difference between `A & B` and `A&B`? and likewise, how's `A<B` different from `A < B`?

Comment: @geekpanth3r, the difference is in what character follows the ampersand or the less than character. In HTML, an `&` may be used as such when not followed by a name start character, so `& B` is OK (the following character is a space) but `&B` is not (the following character is a letter, and `&B` would be parsed as an entity reference, which is then found undefined). Similarly, `< B` is formally OK, but `<B` would be parsed as starting a tag.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The characters `< > & "` are reserved by XML format.

- It means that you can use < and > chars only to define tags (`<mytag></mytag>`).
- Double quotes (") are used to define values of attributes (`<mytag attribute="value" />`)
- Ampersand (&) is used to write entities (`&amp;` is used when you actually want to write ampersand, NOT `&`). Also, when you write url in your XML document, you should use `&amp;`, not just `&`: `www.aaa.com?a=1&b=2` - is wrong; `www.aaa.com?a=1&amp;b=2` - is good!

XHTML is based on XML, so what I have wrote applies to XHTML.

`© ° £` - These are not reserved chars. These are entities defined specifically for XHTML, not for XML.

In XML you can simply write `©`. In XHMTL you can also simply write ©, or use entity `&copy;`, or numeric entity `&00A9;`.

Comment: `(remove space, StackOverflow requires me to set in space)` -- You should use markdown. I've formatted your answer properly. :) And thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, it might help to know that there are also forbidden characters: all control characters in ASCII and ISO-8859-1 except TAB, LF, and CR.

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html