# How do I post a sample of PHP code on my webpage?

Tags: html

I want to post a sample of some code I've written. I'm aware of the `<code></code>` tags, but the problem is that the PHP inside will actually get interpreted and executed when the page loads. What is the way around this?

Comment: Don't include the opening and closing PHP tags

Comment: @henrywright You certainly can include them, and would often want to when demonstrating PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be encoding your entities anyway, which will prevent PHP from parsing them.

Instead of `<?php`, use `&lt;php`.

See also:  [What Are The Reserved Characters In (X)HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10371493/362536)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the source of an entire PHP script, you can use the [`show_source()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php) function. For example,

```
show_source("sample.php");
```

If you want to display the code of the current page, you can do something like

```
show_source(__FILE__);
```

You can also use [`hightlight_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) in place of `show_source()`.

If you were looking to display just a random line of code, you can use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). For example,

```
htmlspecialchars(" <b> This will be a bold text </b> ");
```

**A tip on the aside:** Please look around, and google *atleast* once before asking. `:)`