# Displaying tags in HTML5

Tags: html

In HTML5, if you include `<pre>` for example on a paragraph text, the result won't display `'<pre>'` on the paragraph, and it will run the command `<pre>` on the words after it.

What I have to do display texts **including** signs like `" "` or `<>` on a text, without running the command.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: do you have some code ? because i can write `<p> Hello "World"</p>` without problem in HTML5

Comment: try adding a  command in between, just to write it as an example using <> signs

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are known as [**HTML entities**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp): characters that are reserved, and which automatically get parsed to the the relevant HTML. Using these tags allow you to write out the entities that would usually automatically get parsed as HTML.

For example, attempting to write out the `<pre>` tag within a parent `<pre>` tag will normally result in the inner tag being treated as HTML:

```html
<pre><pre>The relevant tags surround this text</pre></pre>
```

Though using the HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` for the left and right bracket respectively parses the entities as HTML, where they get displayed as text:

```html
<pre>&lt;pre&gt;The relevant tags surround this text&lt;/pre&gt;</pre>
```

A full list of HTML entities can be found **[here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks Obsidian Age, it really helped a lot...I can fix it now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to *escape* the provided content to display it as-is, without it being interpreted as HTML.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/escape-goat

This involves taking the [reserved characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371493/what-are-the-reserved-characters-in-xhtml) for the given language (e.g. HTML) and converting them to a representation that either uses an escape sequence or only uses unreserved characters.

In this case, HTML prescribes the use of [entities](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes) to display characters that would otherwise be used by the syntax for tags and attributes within the source code itself.

Answer (score 0):

The 'best' way is to replace every `< and >` element with `&lt; and &gt:`

But if you want to do it fast, you can use the `xmp` tag. It's deprecated but is still supported by all browsers

```
<xmp>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</xmp>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp